# Making a nested list with php foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to make a nested list with php by using a foreach loop but I'm kind of stuck now. My code uses a foreach loop and checks if the item is a heading, if it is it will start a nested list below it. The problem now is that if it's not a heading I want to put the corresponding list items into a **single** ul element below its heading. Now as you can see it puts every single list items that isn't a heading into a seperate ul element of its own because of the foreach loop. How can I fix this?

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($listitems as $listitem) :  ?>

        <?php if( $listitem['heading'] == 1) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $listitem['listitem']; ?><!--begin nested list-->
        <?php endif; ?>             

        <?php if( $listitem['heading'] == 0) : ?>                   
                <ul><li><?php echo $listitem['listitem']; ?></li></ul>                                                          
        <?php endif; ?>                         

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </li><!--end nested list-->
</ul>
```

This is the desired html output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Javascript Basics<!--begin nested list-->
                <ul>
                    <li>Getting Started</li>
                    <li>Data and Variables</li>
                    <li>Functions</li>
                    <li>Scope</li>
                    <li>Working With Objects</li>
                    <li>Creating Objects</li>
                    <li>Arrays</li>
                    <li>Conditions And Decisions</li>
                    <li>Loops</li>
                </ul>
            </li><!--end nested list-->
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show the desired html structure?

Comment: Working on it, I'm not that familiar with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the inner lists start and end tags when the heading changes.

Something like this

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $NonHeadCount = 0;
    $HeadingOpen = false;
    foreach($listitems as $listitem)
    {
        if( $listitem['heading'] == 1)
        {
            $HeadingOpen = true;
            if ($NonHeadCount != 0)
            {
                echo "</ul>";
            }
            echo "<li>".$listitem['listitem'];
            $NonHeadCount = 0;
        }           

        if( $listitem['heading'] == 0)
        {
            if ($NonHeadCount == 0)
            {
                echo "<ul>";
            }
            echo "<li>".$listitem['listitem']."</li>";
        }

    }
    if ($NonHeadCount != 0)
    {
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    if ($HeadingOpen)
    {
        echo "</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the $listitems format.

Some like this:

```
<?php
    $listitems = array(
      'item1' => array(
         'item11',
         'item12',
         'item13'
      ),
      'item2' => array(
         'item21',
         'item22',
      ),
      'item3',
      'item4'
    );

?>
```

Then, do this:

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";

    foreach($listitems as $item => $listitem):
       echo "<li>$item</li>";
       if(count($listitem) > 0):
          echo "<ul>";
            foreach($lisitem as $item):
                echo "<li>$item</li>";
            endforeach;
          echo "</ul>";
       endif;
    endforeach;


   echo "<ul>";
    ?>
```